# DataAdapter update method progress status

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, dataset, freeze, insert-update

VB2010 using Access2007 as a backend. I am creating a DataSet and adding several DataTables to it and populating them. Most tables have a small amount of records but one can have up to a million records. When I issue my .Update command, is there any way to get the status of where it's at so I can let the user know its x% done updating?

It works great but the app hangs up while doing the update.

```
RowsUpdated = daNewParts.Update(dsInventory, "NewParts")
```

Comment: Enable batch processing and handle the `RowUpdated` event which is fired for every batch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OleDbDataAdapter has two events called [RowUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.rowupdated.aspx) and [RowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.rowupdating.aspx) that you can use to receive the notification when a row has been updated or before the update event.

```
AddHandler daNewParts.RowUpdated, New OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf OnRowUpdated)

Sub OnRowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)
   .....
End Sub
```

this is just the first part of the problem, now you need to know how many rows will be updated when you start the operation. This could be obtained calling GetChanges on the DataTable that you are updating

```
Dim count As Integer
Dim changedData = dsInventory.Tables("NewParts").GetChanges()
if changedData IsNot Nothing Then
   count = changedData.Rows.Count
End If
```

now you could build your progress bar

Comment: ahh yes thank you. i had searched for a while but didnt know what key word to look for. with your example and MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdated%28v=vs.100%29.aspx i was able to implement.